# Drawing a diagonal dashed arrow from A to C

Tags: tikz-arrows, arrows, tikz-cd

Here is the commutative diagram I have:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
A \arrow[r] \arrow[d] &[0.5em] 
D \arrow[d, "{(\beta_1 , \beta_2 , \beta_3)}"] \\
B \arrow[r, "f'"'] & C 
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

Also, I want to add a right arrow beside C, is adding "& \arrow[r] X" to the above code beside C is the correct way to do it?

Comment: Please can you put your screenshot to understand your request adding a your drawing, if is it possible? Thank you very much.

Comment: Sure, next time I will do that. Sorry about that @Sebastiano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
A \arrow[r] \arrow[d] \arrow[dashed]{dr}
 &[0.5em] D \arrow[d, "{(\beta_1 , \beta_2 , \beta_3)}"] \\
B \arrow[r, "f'"']  
  & C \arrow[r] 
  & X
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```